# Domain for triple integral

Tags: calculus

I am in doubt with regards to how to set up the integral bounds and in which order.

$ \int_R  \text{ at the domaine } $ $\{\;(x,y,z)\; |\; 0 \leq z \leq 1 - x^2 - \frac{y^2}{4}\} $

How do i set up the integration bounds correctly?

PROGRESS:

So I have plugged in the shape in Geogebra: $x2+y^2/4$ and then two planes: z=0 and z=1. So I clearly see the shape I have to integrate and from which points. But Im not quite shure how to write the bounds, feel like I'm guessing. My initial line of thinking is that x,y,z all share a beginning point at (0,0,0) and then they move in their respective directions until z = 1:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} \int_0^{y^2/4} dydxdz$

Is that the correct way to conceptualize is?

Comment: The first step in setting up the bounds of a multiple integral is to envision the domain of integration. Are you able to do this? What does your domain look like?

Comment: Consider $z = 0$, $z = 1$ . What cross sections (parallel to $XY$ plane) do you get? It is an inverted elliptic paraboloid with vertex at $(0, 0, 1)$ and you need to integrate between $0 \leq z \leq 1$. As you can see, $z$ cannot be greater than $1$. Also using cylindrical coordinates for integral will make things easier.

Comment: @Math Lover: Thank you so much you reply! Setting z = 0, z = 1 gives me two parallel planes in the 3-D space. So I guess it is between these two planes I have to integrate which is expressed with $0 \leq z \leq 1 $. It makes a lot of sense to think of it as the shape inverted elliptic paraboloid, as you wrote. I have tried to rewrite is as: $ z= -(x^2/1)-y^2/4$ By using the formula $z = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2$. Does this make sense? Is it the minus signs in my case, what makes it 'inverted'? Thank you again for you help!

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you for your reply. Yes, I think I'm closer to envision the domain. Geogebra is very helpful. I can envision the shape and how the z-planes cuts through. And as I understand now, it is this region I have to integrate. I think now it is the last technicalities I need to be sure of.

Comment: It is $(x^2/1) + y^2/4 \leq 1-z$. So as $z$ decreases, the radius of the ellipse increases. $1-z$ increases as value of $z$ reduces from $1$. For example, radius of ellipse for $z = - 3$ is more than radius of ellipse for $z = 0$. For example, at $z = - 3$, the equation of ellipse is $(x^2/4) + y^2/16 = 1$ which means $a = 2, b = 4$ whereas at $z = 0$, $a = 1, b = 2$.

Comment: I have made some progress (I think). Is this the right way to set up the integrals?